# Outlook Exchange 2016 not apply conditional

Tags: html, outlook, ms-office

I have an template email, it actually working with Outlook from Office 2013, 2019 and 365 but i have an issue with Outlook Exchange 2016 : The `<!--[if mso]>` condition is not apply.

This the the code that is not apply :

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, table, td {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: black !important;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true">
<v:fill type="tile" size="100%,100%" src="cid:{{ myBackground }}" color="#fff"/>
</v:background>
<![endif]-->
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work on this specific version of outlook :(

Does anyone has the answer ?

Comment: Having a similar problem with Outlook Exchange 2019.
The mso conditionals are completely ignored here.

Comment: No solution found on my side